# WPS Spreadsheets - How to import data from http to a cell in wps

Tags: office365, spreadsheet

I have some cells that need to import data from **a link/HTTP** and it need to update every 30 minutes.

the HTTP link just returns a value of number.

any idea How to achieve this using `WPS Office SpreadSheet`?

Thank You